# What's the dependency for Android Espresso package `android.support.test.espresso.intent`?

Tags: android, testing, android-intent, dependencies, android-espresso

I came across an interesting package containing in particular the [Intents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/intent/Intents.html) class for testing Intent sending, as well as the IntentMatchers class, as the snippet listed on the Intents class page shows:

```
Intent resultData = new Intent();
String phoneNumber = "123-345-6789";
resultData.putExtra("phone", phoneNumber);
ActivityResult result = new ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData);

// Set up result stubbing when an intent sent to "contacts" is seen.
intending(toPackage("com.android.contacts")).respondWith(result));
```

But when I got to try it, Android Studio complained about not knowing these classes. I checked the Espresso jars (espresso-core and espreso-contrib) listed on the [android-test-kit website](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSetupInstructions) and indeed I could not find any `android.support.test.espresso.intent` package in these jars. Is there any dependency I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2'
```

See https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoIntentsSetupInstructions for more information.